# Missing "six" module for astropy after using cx_freeze/py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze, astropy, six

I was trying to convert program written in python 3 to .exe using cx_freeze and py2exe. But after converting and running program i get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "astroConverter.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Konrad\PycharmProjects\astroConverter\mainwindow.py", line 2, in <module>
    from widgets.widgets import MainMenu, Toolbar, TextField
  File "C:\Users\Konrad\PycharmProjects\astroConverter\widgets\widgets.py", line 1, in <module>
    from widgets.menus import FileMenu, EditMenu, HelpMenu
  File "C:\Users\Konrad\PycharmProjects\astroConverter\widgets\menus.py", line 2, in <module>
    from common import Info
  File "C:\Users\Konrad\PycharmProjects\astroConverter\common.py", line 2, in <module>
    from astropy.io import fits
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\astropy\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    _check_numpy()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\astropy\__init__.py", line 61, in _check_numpy
    from .utils import minversion
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .codegen import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\codegen.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .introspection import find_current_module
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\introspection.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..extern import six
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\astropy\extern\six.py", line 60, in <module>
    _import_six()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\astropy\extern\six.py", line 57, in _import_six
    "distribution.".format(_SIX_MIN_VERSION))
ImportError: Astropy requires the 'six' module of minimum version 1.7.3; normally this is bundled wi
th the astropy package so if you get this warning consult the packager of your Astropy distribution.`

This is my cx_freeze setup.py script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

buildExeOptions = {"packages": ["astropy", "numpy", "matplotlib"],
                   "includes": ["six"],
                   "silent": ["-s"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
setup(name='astroConverter',
      version="0.4",
      description="Format converter used in astronomy",
      options={"build_exe": buildExeOptions},
      executables=[Executable("astroConverter.py", base=base)]
      )
```

and py2exe script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['astroConverter.py'])
```

Here is output for `pip freeze`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip freeze
astropy==1.0.1
cx-Freeze==4.3.4
matplotlib==1.4.3
numpy==1.9.2
py2exe==0.9.2.2
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.4.1
pytz==2015.2
six==1.9.0
UNKNOWN==0.0.0
virtualenv==13.1.0
```

As you can see, my `six` module is in newer version than required by astropy.
Strange thing is, i have all packages properly installed, and while running `python astroConverter.py` everything works fine. This is GUI application (it's using tkinter). Does anyone know how can i force cx_freeze or py2exe to properly include "six" module?

Comment: Try changing both `continue` statements to `raise` in [this function](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/master/astropy/extern/six.py#L35) - it might help you see what is actually going wrong.

Comment: After converting i get error `ImportError: No module named 'astropy'`. I have changed both `continue` to `raise` in six.py.

Comment: Astropy doesn't fully work with py2exe in the first place.  See: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/960  

We have gotten it to work but it takes a little effort, and that patch hasn't been updated in a long while.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Your answer saved a lot of my time.